# Formatting string in sweetalert JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have API that returns me this string :

```
string.Format(
  "Something went wrong with {0}." +
    "<br>" +
    " Do you want to continue with?" +
    "<strong>" +
    "{1}" +
    "</strong>",
);
```

And I want to pass it to SweetAlert2. But this is the result :

[image]

I tried also with **\r\n** and **\n** but nothing happened.

This is my JavaScript :

```
var mess = "@messaggio";
Swal.fire({
  heightAuto: false,
  title: "Richiesta Disconnessione",
  html: mess,
  icon: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
  cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes",
  cancelButtonText: "No",
});
```

I want to put the second phrase under the first and the last word should be bold.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you achieve the desired result by hard coding the Swal.fire() call ?
My guess is that the returned error in your API is escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of sweetalert

Check out more information: https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/

```js
// First, checks if it isn't implemented yet.
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}

var mess = "Something went wrong with {0}.\nDo you want to continue with {1}?".format("Macchina", "carrello"); 
swal(mess,{
  heightAuto: false,
  title: 'Richiesta Disconnessione',
  icon: 'warning',
  buttons: {
  cancel: {
    text: "No",
    value: null,
    visible: true,
    className: "sweet-cancel",
    closeModal: true,
  },
  confirm: {
    text: "Yes",
    value: true,
    visible: true,
    className: "sweet-confirm",
    closeModal: true
  }
}
})
```

```css
.sweet-confirm { color: #3085d6; }
.sweet-cancel { color: #d33; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's the same, notthing change

Comment: As you can see from my snippet it is not the same